# JSONError | No data, empty input at 1:1

Tags: rest, api, postman

I'm tring to print the response code in the console, but i always end up in getting the response as "JSONError | No data, empty input at 1:1"

im getting this error when the response code is 204. else condition works fine.

script is not entering to the condition.

please review the  code and provide a solution. Thanks.

```
var respcode=pm.response.code;
var stagresbody=pm.response.json(responseBody);

if (respcode === 204) { 
    pm.test("engine is suspended with resposne code"+respcode,function(){ 
        console.log(respcode); 
    }) 
}
else { pm.test("Staging is resumed with message"+stagresbody.serviceStatus,function(){
    console.log("Staging is resumed with message "+stagresbody.serviceStatus);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: var respcode=pm.response.code;
var stagresbody=pm.response.json(responseBody);
if (respcode === 204) {
   pm.test("engine is suspended with resposne code"+respcode,function(){
   console.log(respcode);
})
} else { pm.test("Staging is resumed with message"+stagresbody.serviceStatus,function(){
    console.log("Staging is resumed with message "+stagresbody.serviceStatus);
});
}

Comment: You should just need to use `pm.response.json()` without adding `responseBody`

Comment: It would be better if you added your comment to the original question and format the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I have taken the code you wrote in your comment and put it in a code block within the question. Please review the code block to ensure that nothing has been left out from the commented code

Comment: @inputforcolor thx for that.. from next time on ill add it in question.

Comment: @DannyDainton; if i do not use responseBody, the console log is not showing any output just shows as object . Not sure why the code is not working if the response code is 204. And when get response code as 204 the response body do not have anything. so i'm using response code to print on out put

Comment: `pm.response.json()` is the correct syntax `pm.response.json(responseBody)` is something you've made up  - it will work that wrong way as that function ignores any arguments inside it.

Comment: It's more than likely failing on the 204 because for both conditions, you're still parsing the response body - If the 204 response returns no body, it's still trying to parse...well, nothing and then throws the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use this to do the same thing:

```
if (pm.response.code === 204) { 
    pm.test(`Engine is suspended with resposne code ${pm.response.code}`, () => { 
        console.log(pm.response.code); 
    }) 
}
else { 
    pm.test(`Staging is resumed with message ${pm.response.json().stagresbody.serviceStatus}`, () => {
        console.log(`Staging is resumed with message ${pm.response.json().stagresbody.serviceStatus}`);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or accept the answer if it helped you. 

Answer (score 0):

My Postman Test has console log for json response. But my request would not give any response ( i.e. response body is blank ) and thereby giving "No data, empty input at 1:1" error.
I resolved this problem by commenting logging of response.

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function () {
pm.response.to.have.status(204);

});

// Below line would give me error "JSONError | No data, empty input at 
//1:1" as my request won't output ant response i.e. response body is blank.
// Commenting this line resolve problem.

*//console.log( pm.response.json()[0].name);*
```